Sticky position bottom of div at offset from top of screen
I am attempting to create a transition where each section becomes sticky when the bottom of that section is at 33vh from the top of the screen, and then the next section scrolls overtop it. The issue I'm having is that the sections are all of variable heights, and I am attempting to set their sticky position based off how far the bottom of the div is from the top of the screen.
In the snippet below, the transition between "Section 2" and "Section 3" is the desired effect.
As is apparent in the snippet, "Section 1" gets cut off, there's a bunch of empty space at the end, and "Section 4" seems to not be visible anywhere.
Ideally, I would like a pure CSS/tailwind solution. However, this is part of a site built in React, using Framer Motion for animations, and I am open to any working solutions.
Thanks!


.container {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
}

.section1 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, blue, orange);
  flex-direction: column;
  /* hack to get top section to not be covered up by transform */
  margin-bottom: 220vh;
}

.section {
  /* translate up so that position is 0 when the last 33vh of div is visible */
  transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 33vh));
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  height: 240vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, blue, orange);
}

.flex-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="section1">
    <div class="flex-div">
      <h1>Section 1 top</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-div">
      <h1>Section 1 bottom</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="flex-div">
      <h1>Section 2 top</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-div">
      <h1>Section 2 bottom</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="flex-div">
      <h1>Section 3 top</h1>
    </div>
    <div className="flex-div">
      <h1>Section 3 bottom</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="section">
    <div className="flex-div">
      <h1>Section 4 top</h1>
    </div>
    <div className="flex-div">
      <h1>Section 4 bottom</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




If you want the bottom to be 33% from the top have you tried setting bottom 66% rather than setting top and transforming?

I have, however all divs get stacked and stick immediately https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cocky-chandrasekhar-vsq3nk
